# Custom wordpress loop

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

I'm trying to list posts in a custom post type, within a layout like following.

[image]

html for below layout like this.

```
 <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
 PROFILE - 1

 </div>
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">


  </div> 
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
 PROFILE - 2

  </div>
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
 PROFILE - 3

  </div>
 <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">


  </div>

 <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
  PROFILE - 4

   </div>
```

as you can see after "PROFILE - 1" there is a div separator then there is "PROFILE - 1 & PROFILE - 2" after "PROFILE - 1 & PROFILE - 2" again div separator.

basically the structure as follows.

Profile-1

V V

Empty space (div based col-md-4 col-sm-6 )

V V

Profile-2

V V

Profile-3

V V

Empty space (div based col-md-4 col-sm-6 )

V V

Profile-4

i'm using this loop as a custom structure but i'm unable to get it from Profile-2 > Profile-3 > Space point.

looking for a help to achieve this loop

I have tried this so far

```
  <?php 
 $args=array(
'post_type' => 'ourteam',
'posts_per_page' => -1 
 );

   //Set up a counter
   $counter = 0;

  //Preparing the Loop
  $query = new WP_Query( $args );


  //In while loop counter increments by one $counter++
  if( $query->have_posts() ) : while( $query->have_posts() ) : $query-
  >the_post(); $counter++;

  //We are in loop so we can check if counter is odd or even
  if( $counter % 2 == 0 ) : //It's even
  ?>


   <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">

   </div>

    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">

    <div class="cp-attorneys-style-2">

      <div class="frame"> <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php 
     the_post_thumbnail(''); ?></a>

        <div class="caption">

          <div class="holder">

            <ul>

             <li><a href="<?php the_field('mem_twitter'); ?>"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a></li>

              <li><a href="<?php the_field('mem_facebook'); ?>"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a></li>

              <li><a href="<?php the_field('mem_linkedin'); ?>"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></a></li>

            </ul>

            <p> </p>

           <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="btn-style-1">Read Profile</a> </div>

        </div>

      </div>

      <div class="cp-text-box">

        <h3><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>

        <em><?php the_field('mem_titles'); ?></em> </div>

    </div>

  </div>      


 <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">

 </div>


<?php
else: //It's odd
?>



  <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">

    <div class="cp-attorneys-style-2">

      <div class="frame"> <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php 
       the_post_thumbnail(''); ?></a>

        <div class="caption">

          <div class="holder">

            <ul>

             <li><a href="<?php the_field('mem_twitter'); ?>"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a></li>

              <li><a href="<?php the_field('mem_facebook'); ?>"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a></li>

              <li><a href="<?php the_field('mem_linkedin'); ?>"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></a></li>

            </ul>

            <p> </p>

           <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="btn-style-1">Read Profile</a> </div>

        </div>

      </div>

      <div class="cp-text-box">

        <h3><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>

        <em><?php the_field('mem_titles'); ?></em> </div>

    </div>

  </div>      



   <?php  


   endif;

    endwhile; wp_reset_postdata(); endif;


     ?>
```

Comment: What you have tried to do so far?

Comment: @ hardik solanki i have update my question please see

Comment: By default, bootstrap used 12 column structure. If you used `col-md-4 col-sm-6` then It'll display 3 divs in desktop and 2 divs in Ipad. So In your case, It'll display like your screenshot.

Comment: @ hardik solanki  this is an html site i'm converting to wordpress so the html layout is already here. but the things is i'm unable to put this layout in a wordpress loop. what i want is achieve the loop as i mentioned in my question

Comment: Then you need to go with @VineetKumarSingh answer. He is already put your div in custome loop structure.

Comment: @greenarrow you shoudn't use Columns as a way to space your elements, you should use the columns when there is content to be place in them. Thus cols "2" and "5" in your structure example shouldn't be there and use content adjustment done with *margin* or *padding* depending on the need.

Answer (score 0):

Listing custom posts is not that complex. All you have to do is query the custom post using WP_Query Function and then list in html format. Here is the code using which you might achieve what you want.

```
    <?php
    global $the_query;

    $args = array (
          'post_type'=>'team',
          'posts_per_page'=>-1,
    );
    // You can change your post type and for more
    // go to this link https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query
    $the_query = new WP_Query($args); ?>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
    <?php
     if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {

        while ( $the_query->have_posts() ){
          $the_query->the_post(); ?>

          <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
         <?php echo get_the_title(get_the_ID()); ?>

     </div>
    <?php
         }//end while


     } //End if
?>
</div><!-- End of row -->
</div><!-- End of container -->
```

Note :- Inside the loop you can print all the value of custom post

Comment: Thanks, but what i want is a custom loop with the structure i mentioned in my question

Comment: <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">Content </div> will repeat in the loop. And once loop has printed all the information. You need to manage using its beautification using css.